# Append to JSON file, without serializing first and then saving the file

Tags: c#, append, .net-5

I have a method and inside the method, I have a `Parallel.ForEach()` to do some stuff. After the stuff is done, I want it to immediately log what it has done to a JSON file.

Currently I have a singleton class that contains a dictionary for all the current JSON entries. When `stuff` is done, I add the newly done `stuff` to the dictionary, and then serialize the whole dictionary, and then save the file.

That's bad, especially if the dictionary is huge, because serializing a lot of data over and over again is just a waste of time. If I could instead save `stuff` directly to the end of the JSON file, I should be able to do it seamlessly.

Since I know I am only appending data, I figured using a FileStream to seek to the end, then doing some hacks would work, but obviously that would mess up the formatting of the file.

Here's an example:

```json
{
  "test": {
    "id": "test",
    "name": "the best test"
  },
  "test2": {
    "id": "test2",
    "name": "the second best test"
  }
}
```

Appending to JSON ("pseudocode" that doesn't really work, but you get the point):

```cs
FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite("file.json");
fs.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.End);
await fs.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("},"), 0, 2);
await fs.WriteAsync(jsonAsBytes, 0, jsonAsBytes.Length);
```

Output:

```json
{
  "test": {
    "id": "test",
    "name": "the best test"
  },
  "test2": {
    "id": "test2",
    "name": "the second best test"
},
"test3": {
  "id": "test3",
  "name": "the third best test"
}
}
```

Is there a more elegant solution? I need to call this "add to json file" method thousands of times. If I serialize the dictionary at the end of the request/application end, it won't save what has already happened, which would be bad.

Comment: *Is there a more elegant solution?* yes .... use database

Comment: @Selvin This is a single binary console application. Using a database for this, would be 1) overkill 2) confusing for the user. Sure I can make a database locally (like sqlite), and then make a "dump sqlite" command, that procudes a JSON file, but that's not elegant either.

Comment: If your only concern is formatting you only need to add two spaces before each line and your solution would work. Another solution is you select something other json like yaml that you can append to it easily

Comment: I don't think, append seem the better solution. Just `fs.Seek(-Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\n}").Length-1, SeekOrigin.End);` to append after the last element. Maybe CSV would be easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should keep the file open so you don't have to seek all the time. Then close it as soon as all your stuff is done and written to the file.

To make sure your parallel stuff doesn't write to the file at the same time, I would create a small Helper class like:

```cs
public class JsonFileAppender : IDisposable
{
    readonly FileStream fs;
    public JsonFileAppender(string filename)
    {
        fs = File.OpenWrite(filename);
        // start with opening the json
        fs.WriteByte((byte)'{');
    }

    public void Append(string content)
    {
        // prepend every line with 2 spaces
        content = string.Join('\n', content.Split('\n').Select(line => $"  {line}"));
        byte[] byteContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);

        // no parallel writes
        lock (fs)
        {
            fs.Write(byteContent, 0, byteContent.Length);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // close the json
        fs.WriteByte((byte)'}');
        // and close the stream
        fs.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```cs
using var jsonFileAppender = new JsonFileAppender("file.json");
jsonFileAppender.Append(jsonPart);
```

You should of course create the JsonFileAppender instance once and use it in your Parallel.ForEach().

*(Code is untested)*

Comment: Right, that solves the threading problem (that I already have taken care of, fortunately). It doesn't solve the biggest issue, which is formatting the file, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, ok. You could handle that in the Append-Method of the JsonFileAppender. If the input to the Append-Method is already pre-formatted that shouldn't be a big deal.
I updated my answer to match your requirement (note that the Append-Method now expects a string instead of byte[]).

Answer (score 0):

If the format isn't enforced, I will consider the possibility of using CSV (can be opened in Excel).

If really it's JSON, I will do minimum JSON (without formatting) and use a other tool to format on reading (Notepadd++, VS Code, online tool, ...).

But to have a nice formatted file, you can add space like :

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var nl = Environment.NewLine;
    var endOfFile = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{nl}}}");

    using FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite("file.json");
    //Set the cusor after the last element
    fs.Seek(-endOfFile.Length, SeekOrigin.End);
            
    //Separate the last element and new element
    fs.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($",{nl}"));
    //Add the new element
    fs.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"  \"test42\": {{{nl}"));
    fs.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"    \"id\": \"test42\",{nl}"));
    fs.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"    \"name\": \"A message with some informations...\"{nl}"));
    fs.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"  }}"));
    //Close root json element
    fs.Write(endOfFile);
}
```

See the use of `Seek` to set the cursor just after the last element. Then append will overwrite the end of file. Why the end of file need to be re-append.